# use jquery to reorder page with droppable and sortable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Im sure this has been asked a million times but i cant find the answer.  I have a list of items that i want the user to be able to drop into any of a few buckets and then be able to post the results to a db.

the jquery:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#items li" ).draggable({
  appendTo: "body",
  helper: "clone"
});

 $( ".bucket" ).droppable({
  activeClass: "ui-state-default",
  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    var liId = ui.draggable.attr('id');
    $(this).append(liId);

    //remove item from original list
     ui.draggable.remove();

  }
  }).sortable({
  items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
  sort: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
  }
});


  //button event

 $('#butSub').click (function()
 {
    var data = $('.bucket').serialize();
                            $.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: "page2.php",
                                            data: data,
                                            success: function(result)
                                            {
                                                    alert(result);  
                                            }
                                    });
  });
```

The items:

```
 <div id='items'>
 <li id='dog'>Dog</li>
 <li id='cat'>Cat</li>
 <li id='fish'>Fish</li>
 <li id='gerbil'>Gerbil</li>
 </div>
```

I have a few divs to choose from:

```
 <div id='rodents' class='bucket'></div>
 <div id='pets' class='bucket'></div>
 <div id='critters' class='bucket'></div>


<input type='button' id='butSub' name='butSub' value='submit'>
```

I am using droppable to be able to drag "dog" to the pets div.  This all works as expected. What i want to do is have a save button, that when the user clicks, i can serialize all the inputs in the correct divs, and populate a db.

the problem is no matter what i put in the selector for var data, i get empty post...

In the end on page2.php i need the div, and all the items in the div.

Comment: Have you wrapped the input (id=butsub) in <form> tags?

Comment: i didn't but added that and no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think serialize is behaving how you are expecting it to. Check out what this fiddle outputs to console:

http://jsfiddle.net/xp6Fv/

### HTML:

```
<div id='rodents' class='bucket'><li id='dog'>Dog</li></div>
```

### JS:

```
console.log($("#rodents").serialize());
```

Serialize is generally used on forms, not vanilla div and list elements.

I think it would be easier if you did something like:

```
var items = [];
$("#rodent").find(".item").each(function(item) {
    items.push(item.id);
});
var json = $.toJson(items);
```

You can then send that JSON over the wire.

Comment: where does find (".item") come from.  there is no item class anywhere.

Comment: @bart2puck That would be added to each `li` element in the `items` div.